# ls -lh vs du -sh * for file sizes within a directory

Tags: linux, directory

In a particular directory I have some files. If I want to check the size of the files, I use the command ls-lh in that directory and I get this as output:

```
total 61G

    -rw-r--r--+ 1   user    user    81  Dec 18  11:50:00 AM sra.o6691673
    -rw-r--r--+ 1   user    user    81  Dec 18  12:16:00 PM sra.o6691674
    -rw-r--r--+ 1   user    user    67G Dec 18  11:50:00 AM SRR531824_1.fastq
    -rw-r--r--+ 1   user    user    73G Dec 18  12:16:00 PM SRR531825_1.fastq
```

First of all total says 61G and I have 2 files which are already 67G and 73G each, so how is total calculated??

Secondly I used the command

```
du -sh *
```

in the same directory and got this as result

```
1.5K    sra.o6691673
1.5K    sra.o6691674
30G SRR531824_1.fastq
32G SRR531825_1.fastq
```

What is the actual size of the files and what should I take into consideration ls-lh or du -sh *.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that the files have more space allocated on disk than they are actually using. Normally I'd expect to see this only in binary files where blocks of NULLs are not stored. Since fastq format is text however I think the file allocation extends past the end of the data. Try the command `ls -lsh` and compare the two sizes listed for each file. Column 1 is the amount of disk space allocated and column 6 is the disk space used.

Comment: Using ls -lsh gives me what i get with du -sh *